# List Windows Network Connections and detect which is connected to the Internet

Tags: winapi

In Delphi XE4, how can I list the network connections on my Windows 7 computer as they are listed in (see screenshot below):
**Windows Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections**

I also need to detect which of them is connected to the Internet.

[image]

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer by removing all mention of Delphi and asking a winapi, language agnostic question. Delphi knows nothing of this. It's pure winapi.

Comment: David, thanks for the hint; but shouldn't it be possible to get this with WMI?

Comment: I would think so. There are win32 apis too.

Comment: Neither `[wmi]` implies what it has to be done in `[delphi]`.